# Catching Exceptions in the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, razorengine

It seems like if an Exception occurs inside a controller, the view-engine won't go to the intended view, even if the "exception" is caught inside a try-catch block?

or I'm missing something here:

```
public ActionResult MyController(int? param1, DateTime? param2)
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    try
    {
        model = new MyModel();

        //AN ERROR HAPPENS HERE (so the code goes to catch the Exception):
        model.Connection.Initialize();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    //when I put a break point I get to this following line, however, "MyView" is never displayed!?
    return PartialView("MyView", model);
}
```

Comment: Maybe model is null or in an invalid state for your view, so you get another error displaying the view

Comment: hmmm, I think you're right. I think Model ends up being null; is there a way to force the view even if its model is null?

Comment: Why would you have a connection in your model?

Comment: The model is not null, *if* the error occurs when you say it does, you successfully "new" it up before the error. However, a member of the model can be null, which could cause an error.

Comment: ok after looking at the "response body", I see the error occurs in the "view" itself. So yeah, as I suspected, the controller code above is valid; it was the view causing the issue; thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be getting another exception afterwards, somewhere in your view. Look at the stack trace that displays on the browser page and fix that.

Comment: exactly; after looking at the "response body", I see the error is occurring in the view itself. thanks!